# Can multiple autorization_code co-exist for a single integration user?

Tags: rest-api, integration, oauth2, authentication, authorization

I have a single integration User, which is used to authenticate a background integration job. This uses web-server flow. And to avoid storing username/password on the server, I have only supplied `authorization_code` instead of Username/Password.

Now, the same User needs to handle another background integration job

The problem now is, if I generate one more authorization_code for the new background integration job, the other code might expire and become invalid.

Is there a way that I can maintain multiple codes?

Comment: the background integration job is it from another system hitting salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have different clients serving different purpose for the same user or for the other way around with the existing client with which you got the Authorization code, extend that client to handle that job as well

Comment: ok...may be a different Connected App for the new job! :)